# print only one string if there is continuous similar strings

Tags: php, string, loops

I have a variable $b = substr($r['pon_port'],4,2); in foreach loop.
Var dump of $b gives a list of strings like this:

```
string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0"
string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1"
string(1) "2" string(1) "2" string(1) "2" string(1) "2" string(1) "2"
string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "3"
string(1) "4" string(1) "4" string(1) "4" string(1) "4" string(1) "4"
string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0" string(1) "0"
string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1"
```

What i want is if there are similar continuous string i want to have only one string > for eg: in above dump . i just want:

```
string(1) "0" 
string(1) "1" 
string(1) "2" 
string(1) "3" 
string(1) "4" 
string(1) "0" 
string(1) "1"
```

Comment: what if same values come in random order like `"0 0 1 0 2 1 2 ..." ` ?

Comment: @Mureinik I tried pushing unique values to empty array. but if same number occurs contiuously in two differrent places like  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 . I am able to get only 0 1 2. what i want i 0 1 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can accomplish this keeping the last number in mind:

```
$lastB = null;
foreach ($foo as $r) //I'm guessing that $r is the dummy variable, based on your code
{
        $b = substr($r['pon_port'],4,2); //You wrote this

        //This part prevents repetitions from happening
        if ($lastB === null || $b != $lastB) var_dump($lastB = $b);
}
```

(In this case, I sneaked the assignment into the argument, using `var_dump($lastB = $b)` instead of two seperate statements. I find it neater, but you can seperate them if you prefer.)

If you want to do something other than printing the variables, as a end result, you can use this code:

```
$lastB = null;
foreach ($foo as $r) //I'm guessing that $r is the dummy variable, based on your code
{
        $b = substr($r['pon_port'],4,2); //You wrote this

        //This part prevents repetitions from happening
        if ($lastB === null || $b != $lastB)
        {
            //do something with $b...
            $lastB = $b;
        }
}
```

Trying the first code myself on the sequence "2 2 7 8 8 7", I get:

```
string(1) "2" string(1) "7" string(1) "8" string(1) "7"
```

Answer (score 0):

My (possibly foolish) assumption based on context is they are always single digit numbers. You can 1-line this but for readability sake:

```
$nums = array(0,0,1,2,2,3,4,0,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,3,4,4,4);
print_r($nums);
$nums = implode('',$nums);
$nums = preg_replace('~(\d)((?=\1).)+~','$1',$nums);
$nums = str_split($nums);
print_r($nums)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 2
    [13] => 1
    [14] => 2
    [15] => 3
    [16] => 3
    [17] => 4
    [18] => 4
    [19] => 4
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 3
    [13] => 4
)
```